# AC-DC converter to drive a dc motor (treadmill)

Tags: voltage, power, dc-motor, rectifier, ac-dc

I would like to fix my treadmill.

I have connected a SCR voltage dimmer (WINGONEER AC 220V 4000W) in series with a full-bridge-rectifier (GBPC5006), to the dc motor. [image: DC motor data]

When I move the potentiometer, the motor runs, but it smokes a little bit and smells.

What is the problem? Is the pulsed wave not good enough? What can I do? And why in the data of the motor is written 50/60Hz if it is a dc one?

Comment: The 50/60 Hz marking must refer to the input to the controller that originally powered the motor. That controller may still be inside the motor housing or it may be in the treadmill. The motor or brushes may be failing.

Comment: A quick search did not turn up a datasheet for your motor. I am concerned that your motor may be a "brushless" DC motor, based upon the fact that a brushed DC motor generally does not have a frequency specification. If it is a brushless DC motor, it needs a special motor controller. A dimmer circuit will not work. How many wires come out of the motor?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy 2 (red and black) and the ground

Comment: OK. Then I think it is safe to assume you have a brushed DC motor. Does the motor smoke whenever there is enough current to turn the motor?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy the potentiometer (5Kohm) is too much big, so I cannot do a linear start. At the begging it doesn't run regularly, but increasing the potentiometer it becomes linear, and starts smelling at a medium velocity.

Comment: @Lisa, I would agree with Charles, and suspect the motor. If you are mechanically inclined, you may want to inspect the brushes and the commutator. DC motor brushes are generally graphite, and as they wear, they leave graphite between the gaps of the commutator. This causes current flow across commutator gaps. A cleaning of the commutator and replacement of the brushes may solve your problem. Or not. If you want to attempt this, I suggest you watch a video first. Also, be aware that brushes are attached to springs and may jump out when the screw caps holding them in place are removed.